# Wrong Thread Exception when changing an object's property from an event delegate

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, windows-runtime, uwp

I have `PlaybackModel` class which I instantiate in the `MainPage` of my app, like so:

```
if(PlaybackModel.Current == null) new PlaybackModel();
```

I use the `PlaybackModel` for storing references to objects I use in my app. It also works as a ViewModel for the majority of pages. It defines these properties, among others:

```
public MediaPlayer player { get; set; }
public MediaPlaybackState playbackState { get; set; }
public RepeatMode repeatMode { get; set; }
public MediaPlaybackList queue { get; set; }
[AlsoNotifyFor("currentIndex", "currentTrack")]
public MediaPlaybackItem currentItem { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<PlaybackItemViewModel> tracks { get; set; }
public int currentIndex {
    get {
        return (int)queue.CurrentItemIndex;
    } set {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CurrentIndex Setter called! Value: "+value);
        if (value >= 0 && queue.Items.Count() > value && value != queue.CurrentItemIndex)
            queue.MoveTo((uint)value);
    }
}
public PlaybackItemViewModel currentTrack { get { if (currentIndex == -1) return null; if (tracks.Count() > currentIndex) return tracks[currentIndex]; else return null; } }
private TimeSpan _currentPosition;
public TimeSpan currentPosition { get { return _currentPosition; } set { _currentPosition = value; player.PlaybackSession.Position = _currentPosition; } }
public TimeSpan currentDuration { get; set; }
public Library library { get; set; }
public LastfmClient lastFm { get; set; }
```

In the inspector of the `PlaybackModel` I'm subscribing to some events to keep track of what's going on with the media player and the queue, so I can later display it in the UI. For example:

```
player.PlaybackSession.PlaybackStateChanged += (o, ea) =>
{
        playbackState = o.PlaybackState;
};
```

But this won't work. It throws a `WRONG_THREAD` exception. It's the same for all these other events. I also tried using the `await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync()` method to run the code on the UI thread but as I understand it, this won't work when the app is in the background playback mode. How can I do it some other way so that it works supports background playback?

For now I decided to use this for my `ItemChanged` event:

```
queue.CurrentItemChanged += async (o, ea) =>
{
    await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        var pos = currentPosition.Duration();
        var bg = App.Ref.IsBackground;
        Task<ScrobbleResponse> res = null;
        currentPosition = TimeSpan.Zero;
        currentItem = o.CurrentItem;
        if (ea.OldItem != null)
        {
            var vm = ea.OldItem.Source.CustomProperties["vm"] as PlaybackItemViewModel;
            if (pos.TotalSeconds >= ea.OldItem.Source.Duration.Value.TotalSeconds * 0.9)
            {
                res = lastFm.Scrobbler.ScrobbleAsync(new Scrobble(vm.Artist, vm.Album, vm.Title, DateTimeOffset.Now));
            }
        }
        if (currentItem != null)
            currentDuration = o.CurrentItem.Source.Duration.Value;
        else currentDuration = TimeSpan.Zero;
    });
};
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, I figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the dispatcher runs correctly. It's the `if` statement that's not being called due to the conditions not updating in the background. My bad.